# Structure to store CIDR-friendly non-intersecting IP ranges

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.5

What would be the storage schema that would allow to search the range the given IP address falls into that provides a way to be optimized using index.

So: there is a set of *non-intersecting* IP addresses ranges (that might be represented in CIDR notation if necessary).

And it's required to match the range a given IP address matches.

So it will always be exactly `0..1` matches.

`ip_from (int), ip_to (int)` does not qualify the task, since you cannot optimize search through it using B-Tree (or any other index structure available in mysql).

Comment: Maybe it's a solution to store each IP segmental number in a different db-field? Like `ip_segment_1`, `ip_segment_2`, etc. and query based on that? It's nearly impossible to let the database use the BTREE (or any indexing) when it needs to detect patterns. The likeliness it needs to inspect every table-entry is nearly 100%.

Comment: @Allendar spatial indexes can do that actually :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it - `from-to` schema works:

One needs to get all IPs prefixes for a given IP address and use the `from IN (<prefixes_list_here>)` check.